# File format of g++ executable

Tags: shell, g++, file-format

I know that in linux system the extension is quite useless but the g++ executable must have a file format at all.
I read about ELF but I'm not sure.

There is a shell command that shows the format of any file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the command is called `file`, here is some documentation about the command:
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_file.htm

[Example of using the file command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS1UK.png)